# Why useState sets data only when you click to button for the second time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I tried to set value in useState, but it works only when I click the button for the second time, why it can happens?

```
const DropDownMenu = ({ element, segmentEnd, segmentStart }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [ratio, setRatio] = React.useState("");

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const openFitToScreen = () => {
    setRatio("Fit to screen");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const openFitToHeight = () => {
    setRatio("Fit to height");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const openFitToWidth = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setRatio("Fit to width");
  };

  const openOriginal = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setRatio("Original");
  };

  return (
    <Box style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Box>
        <Box onClick={handleToggle} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          {ratio !== "" ? ratio : element.ratio}
        </Box>
        <Popper
          open={open}
          role={undefined}
          transition
          disablePortal
          style={{ position: "absolute", top: 20, zIndex: 1000 }}
        >
          {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
            <Grow
              {...TransitionProps}
              style={{
                transformOrigin:
                  placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom",
              }}
            >
              <Paper>
                <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                  <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="menu-list-grow">
                    <MenuItem value="Original" onClick={() => openOriginal()}>
                      Original
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      value="Fit to screen"
                      onClick={() => openFitToScreen()}
                    >
                      Fit to screen
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      value="Fit to height"
                      onClick={() => openFitToHeight()}
                    >
                      Fit to height
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      value="Fit to width"
                      onClick={() => openFitToWidth()}
                    >
                      Fit to width
                    </MenuItem>
                  </MenuList>
                </ClickAwayListener>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          )}
        </Popper>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I tried to set value in useState, but it works only when I click the button for the second time, why it can happens?
I tried to set value in useState, but it works only when I click the button for the second time, why it can happens?

Comment: Where is the button in the code?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress MenuItem

Comment: `{ratio !== "" ? ratio : element.ratio}` what is `element` here?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress data from back-end

Comment: But it isn't defined, don't you get an error for that?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress why should i get an error? I got data from BE, and it shows it, then when i change on onClick it shows new value, but doesn't set to useState -  setRatio. And it sets only for second click

Comment: Ok got it, does this sorted your problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7xhkc

Answer (score 0):

Which value is set the second time?

```
useCallBack(() => <Popper>....</Popper>, [open])
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you do that :

```
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen); // your state need to be a boolean not a function
  };
```

instead try to do this :

```
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(!prevOpen);
  };
```